# Add a calendar on Android

Tags: android, calendar

I'd like to add a new calendar for my application (to divide it from other events), as GMail does.

If there isn't a way to that, how could we delete our events from the calendar when the app is disinstalled?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The contract for the calendars can be found [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Calendars.html) However, you need the account name and type to be able to insert a new calendar. I'm guessing gmail can do this since it has your google account info - I'm not sure if your app will be able to do the same.

As for your second questions, [here is the spec for calendar events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html). You will just need to know the `_ID` of the event in the DB to be able to remove it (which you should be able to get fairly easily).

> Events can be deleted either by the _ID as an appended id on the Uri or using any standard selection. If an appended id is used a selection is not allowed. There are two versions of delete: as an app and as a sync adapter. An app delete will set the deleted column on an event and remove all instances of that event. A sync adapter delete will remove the event from the database and all associated data.

Comment: Can you please post some example code to create an Android Calendar?